# Error in Zookeeper : Unreasonable length = 308375649 when creating topic in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am setting up Kafka on my local Windows 10 machine. So downloaded all the required binaries and updated the two settings server and zookeeper properties as per the documentation.

But when running the Kafka create topic command

```
kafka-topics.bat --create --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic testtopic
```

I am getting below error in the Zookeeper window

```
WARN Close of session 0x0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
java.io.IOException: Unreasonable length = 308375649
        at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.checkLength(BinaryInputArchive.java:166)
        at org.apache.jute.BinaryInputArchive.readBuffer(BinaryInputArchive.java:127)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.proto.ConnectRequest.deserialize(ConnectRequest.java:91)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.processConnectRequest(ZooKeeperServer.java:1350)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.readConnectRequest(NIOServerCnxn.java:419)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.readPayload(NIOServerCnxn.java:180)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:339)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory$IOWorkRequest.doWork(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:522)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.server.WorkerService$ScheduledWorkRequest.run(WorkerService.java:154)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can somebody help me here?

Comment: Voting to close as typo. Port 2181 is Zookeeper, not a `bootstrap-server` (the Kafka server on port **9092**). Also please read https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2/

Answer (score 31):

I faced similar issue, because I was trying to connect to the zookeeper instance (Port 2181) while providing the **--bootstrap-server** option. Later, I provided the Kafka broker details (localhost:9092) & it worked fine.

In the older Kafka version, we used to provide **--zookeeper** option & hence its instance.

Try this command -

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic testtopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1
```

Comment: Think you misspelt port name in the command : 9092 instead of 2181

Answer (score 4):

The issue seems to be because of change between old Kafka/Zookeeper setup vs new one.
In old one we were supposed to use --zookeeper option and port 2181 (by default); however with new Kafka/Zookeeper versions user is expected to use port 9092 by default with customer APIs.
We get error **java.io.IOException: Unreasonable length** when API is issued using new Kafka with port 2181.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following command
kafka-topics.bat --describe --topic testtopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

Comment: kafka-topics.bat --create --topic testtopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092